# Tensorflow: Initializing all variables with a single initializer object

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

In Tensorflow, I wonder if there is a difference between initializing multiple variables with the same initializer object and using a separate initializer for each of them (assuming we use the same initialization method for all variables, of course).

For example:

```
initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
C = tf.get_variable(name="ConvFilter", shape=[5, 5, 1, feature_count], initializer=initializer,
                dtype=tf.float32)
b_c = tf.get_variable(name="ConvBias", shape=(feature_count,), initializer=initializer, dtype=tf.float32)
```

and

```
initializer1 = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
C = tf.get_variable(name="ConvFilter", shape=[5, 5, 1, feature_count], initializer=initializer1 ,
                dtype=tf.float32)
initializer2 = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
b_c = tf.get_variable(name="ConvBias", shape=(feature_count,), initializer=initializer2 , dtype=tf.float32)
```

I guess that when a `tf.global_variables_initializer()`evaluation has been made, in the first case, the same `initializer` object is executed multiple times, using the same seed and in the second example, different objects are executed with different seeds. But I wanted be sure if this is really as I am guessing. Which method should be preferred?

Comment: Have you checked out https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#initialization ?

Comment: Yes, it does not contain the answer I am looking for.